# Cardinality multiplication in counting problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Multiplying things seems to be my weakest point, so I am trying to understand as much as possible.

Consider $\sum^k_{j = 0} \binom mj \binom n{k - j}$. It's the answer to the question: "from a class of $m + n$ students, consisting of $m$ men and $n$ women, how many ways can one form a size $k$ committee?".

Let $m = 5, n = 6, k = 5, j = 3$ where $3 = |\{a, b, c\}|, 2 = |\{d, e\}|\;.$ Then, we have(do we ?) the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
       (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) \\
        (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) \\
        (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) & (\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e\}) \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

From here it's easy to see the reason behind $\binom mj \binom n{k - j}$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Note that there is an additional assumption that $k \leq m$ and $k \leq n$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: No such assumption is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t understand your matrix. Suppose that the $5$ men are $M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_5$, and the $6$ women are $W_1,W_2,\ldots,W_6$. If $k=5$ and $j=3$, we’re counting $5$-person committees with $3$ men and $2$ women. There are $\binom53=10$ different sets of $3$ men and $\binom62=15$ different sets of $2$ women, and we can match up any of the $10$ sets of men with any of the $12$ pairs of women, so there are actually $10\cdot12=120$ possible $5$-person committees with $3$ men and $2$ women. The $10\times12$ matrix of these committees is a bit too large to display here, but I’ve shown below the first two columns of it.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
&\{W_1,W_2\}&\{W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\ \hline
\{M_1,M_2,M_3\}&\{M_1,M_2,M_3,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_1,M_2,M_3,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_1,M_2,M_4\}&\{M_1,M_2,M_4,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_1,M_2,M_3,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_1,M_2,M_5\}&\{M_1,M_2,M_5,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_1,M_2,M_3,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_1,M_3,M_4\}&\{M_1,M_3,M_4,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_1,M_3,M_4,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_1,M_3,M_5\}&\{M_1,M_3,M_5,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_1,M_3,M_5,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_1,M_4,M_5\}&\{M_1,M_4,M_5,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_1,M_4,M_5,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_2,M_3,M_4\}&\{M_2,M_3,M_4,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_2,M_3,M_4,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_2,M_3,M_5\}&\{M_2,M_3,M_5,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_2,M_3,M_5,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_2,M_4,M_5\}&\{M_2,M_4,M_5,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_2,M_4,M_5,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\{M_3,M_4,M_5\}&\{M_3,M_4,M_5,W_1,W_2\}&\{M_3,M_4,M_5,W_1,W_3\}&\ldots\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you. Apparently I didn't bother computing the number of combinations correctly. Here's a little discussion we had about this on another site: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/34ir6m/cardinality_multiplication_in_counting_problems/ The last question on there doesn't stand anymore. I found a nice definition in an encyclopedia :)

Comment: @shake-up: You’re welcome.